# What the relations between return value and msg argument of function tcp_recvmsg in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, kernel

I want to add a function to do something when the data over TCP will be delivered to userspace, so I add the code in inet_recvmsg() as follows:

```
int inet_recvmsg(struct socket *sock, struct msghdr *msg, size_t size, int flags)
{
    struct sock *sk = sock->sk;
    int addr_len = 0;
    int err;
    sock_rps_record_flow(sk);
    err = sk->sk_prot->recvmsg(sk, msg, size, flags & MSG_DONTWAIT,
                   flags & ~MSG_DONTWAIT, &addr_len);
    if (err >= 0)
        msg->msg_namelen = addr_len;

    //my code here begin
    if (err > 0 && sk->sk_family == IPPROTO_TCP)
        my_function(sk, msg, err);
    //my code here end

    return err;
}
```

I understand that if the caller receives some data successfully, this function will return err>0 which means the length of data copied to the buffer supplied by userspace, and the received data have already been copied to the buffer pointed by msg->iov_iter.iov. But when I debug the my_function(), I meet very strange things:

1. the returned err is 8912, this means the userspace read the data successfully.
2. the msg->iov_iter.nr_segs is 0 which means is the length of array(msg->iov_iter.iov).

Why so that result, or what wrong about my understanding?

Additional, my Linux kernel is 4.9.100

Comment: What values are in other fields of msg, like msg_control? What was the msg before recvmsg?

Comment: I really don't notice the values of other fields of msg, but I know the value of msg->iov_iter.type is 0(means READ). Actually, I just want to know how should I visit the data that kernel copied into buffer.